# How to validate array of fields using Vuelidate 2 and the Options API in a Vue 3 app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, validation, vuejs3, vuelidate

I am working on a `Vue 3` app and I am trying to validate a nested array of fields. I've used the `helpers.forEach` so far but it does not seem to work for some reason.

Here are my validations:

```
validations: {
    form: {
        name: {
            required,
            maxLength: maxLength(64),
        },
        location: {
            maxLength: maxLength(191),
        },
        duty_cycle: {
            required,
            integer,
            minValue: minValue(0),
        },
        sensors: {
            $each: helpers.forEach({
                position: {
                    integer,
                    minValue: minValue(0),
                },
                sensor_settings: {
                    $each: helpers.forEach({
                        has_alarm: {
                            boolean: (on_off) => {if (on_off === true || on_off === false) {return true;} else {return false;}},
                        },
                        min_value: {
                            decimal,
                        },
                        max_value: {
                            decimal,
                        },
                    })
                },
            })
        },
    }
},
```

Here is how I access the errors:

```
v$.form.sensors.$each.$response.$errors[index].sensor_settings.$each.$response.$errors[i].field_name
```

but I keep getting:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$response')
```

when accessing the second `$response`.

I've browsed through the docs of `vuelidate` - nothing so far. Googled a ton of things. Even tried `ChatGPT` and `Bard`.

Any ideas why that might happen?

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that `$response` is not present at certain levels, leading to `"Cannot read properties of undefined."` Try simplifying your validation structure and accessing errors like this:

```
v$.form.sensors.$each[index].sensor_settings.$each[i].field_name
```

This assumes that `sensors` and `sensor_settings` are arrays, not objects with `$each` properties. If they are indeed objects, ensure they are initialized properly.

If the issue persists, consider checking the data you're working with during runtime. Sometimes, the error might be due to missing or incorrectly structured data rather than the Vuelidate configuration.

Remember, Vue 3 and Vuelidate 2 might have updates, so checking their documentation or community forums for any specific issues could also be helpful.

Comment: Tried that but did not work. Including `.sensors[index].sensor_settings...`. But looking at the `v$` object the original way is the way to go.

Comment: Found the right way: `v$.form.sensors.$each.$response.$errors[index].sensor_settings[0].$response.$errors[i].min_value`